# Should I commit ad code to my git repository?

Tags: html, database, git, ads

Here's the dilemma: I use several different ad companies and ad types on my site due to varying RPM/fill rate. Currently, I am committing all ad changes to the site directly into master, including whenever I change companies. Some of these ads also require special formatting since the companies who set these up didn't bother to test them well on mobile.

This is all just HTML ad code, including my publisher token. These aren't private since the end-user's browser will get them, but I don't really like committing any kind of token since it may change, plus it is still very much a pain to change the code, commit, push/pull, etc. Plus it really litters the git history with many "Changing ad company to xxxx" commits.

A solution that I thought may work would be using a database column to hold the html for the ad code, but I feel that it would increase the risk of XSS in the case someone had compromised access to the database, and it's impractical since I would probably need multiple anyway since some ads require special formatting depending on where on the page they are placed.

Is there a best practice when dealing with ads on a website tracked in git?

Comment: How often do you change ad companies and/or tokens?

Comment: Please be aware that asking questions like "Is there a best practice" is asking for opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have code variants.

You should keep all of them in version control and keep a backup. This is best practice.

---

I will sketch up 2 pathways to start from. This is not best practice because there is none and the details are way to broad for SO.

*using git*

Use a branch for each variant. And check out the one you need in "production".

*using code*

Just keep both codes and use a "switch" to toggle between them. You could keep the state of that switch in a config file or database along with your tokens. You will need a default value and I'm voting for "no ads at all".